# Converting Single Liked List to a Doubly Linked List using class inheritance

Tags: c++, oop

I managed to create the single linked list using the following class named node:

```
class node
{
    protected: 
    int info;  //value
    int lenght;
    node *next;
    node *head;
};
```

(In public I have the working funcitons). And the other class double_node:

```
class double_node : public node
{ 
   protected : node *prev;
};
```

My issue here is using the add function in the double_node class, where I have two problems (modified it alteast 10 times but I'll post the one with all errors I got, because I'm not sure the other versions fixed any of them):

```
void add (int x){
double_node *p = new double_node(x); // constructor makes next = NULL & info = x
if (head == NULL)
    {
        p->prev = NULL;
        head = p;
    }
else
{
    double_node* q = head; //#1st issue, no idea how to initialize a pointer with head
    while (q->next!= NULL)
    {
        q = q->next; //#2nd issue
    }
    q->next= p;
    p->prev= q;
}
```

}

Both errors are : invalid conversion from 'node*' to 'double_node*' [-fpermissive].
Any ideeas to fix this? Or maybe another way to create the doubly linked list?
Thanks in advance!

Note: posted it on code review but I was told it would fit better here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring a `node*` instead of a `double_node*` in `add` function should suffice.

You can always assign a pointer to a subclass to its ancestor, but the opposite is not valid.

Something like the following should suffice:

```
   void add (int x){
    node *p = new double_node(x); 
    if (head == NULL)
    {
       head = p;
    }
    else
    {
        node* q = head; 
        while (q->next!= NULL)
        {
            q = q->next; //#2nd issue
        }
        q->next= p;
        static_cast<double_node*>(p)->prev= q;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I am declaring as node* I am not allowed to acces the members as they are private and the add function is a method of double_node class.